# MySQL NodeJS prepared statement on INSERTING OR UPDATING table name?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm

Here is the code I am looking to do:

```
connection.query({
sql: 'CREATE TABLE ? ( `wage` FLOAT NOT NULL , `monday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `tuesday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `wednesday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `thursday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `friday`) ENGINE = InnoDB;',
timeout: 40000, // 40s
},
//[arg1],
function (error, results, fields) {

if (error) {
console.log("Table creation failed");
}else{
console.log("Table creation success");
}

}

);
```

This does not work as a prepared statement as it takes it and puts it in quotation marks meaning the statement looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE 'test' ( `wage` FLOAT NOT NULL , `monday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `tuesday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `wednesday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `thursday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `friday`) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Which is not valid

So instead I am foced to write the statement like this:

```
connection.query({
sql: 'CREATE TABLE '+arg1+' ( `wage` FLOAT NOT NULL , `monday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `tuesday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `wednesday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `thursday` FLOAT NOT NULL , `friday` FLOAT NOT NULL) ENGINE = InnoDB;',
timeout: 40000, // 40s
},
//[''],
function (error, results, fields) {

if (error) {
console.log("Table creation failed");
}else{
console.log("Table creation success");
}

}

);
```

This works but it now opens me up to SQL injection which is what I am trying to avoid.

Is there any way I can resolve this and use the prepared statements?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql - This is the package I use

Comment: is not possible pass object name as tablename or column name as param so you can use only dinamic sql  ..  for avoid sqliject you must provider a proper purification of your string  ..  for this ee the specific function provided  by your code language

Comment: So how can I make sure it's prepared if I want to pass table names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape query identifiers by using “??” or connection.escapeId().

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers